# Content Type Not Updated docx,xlsx,pptx in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007

SharePoint library items has document has (.docx, .xlsx, .pptx) extension and item associated with custom content type(Blank word document, Document). When user tries to change custom content type to OOTB content type(Document). It’s not updating even there is no error.

Steps to Reproduce:
1.Create a custom content type that parent as "Document".
2.Associate the content type into the document library and add "content types" to All documents view.
3.When library items has document has (.docx,.xlsx,.pptx) extension and item associated with  custom content type.
4.Now try to change custom content type to OOTB "Document" content type and vice-versa.
5.It’s not updating even there is  no error.

Please help on this i faced this issue only in (.docx,.xlsx,.pptx) extensions.

Thanks,
Rajendhiran M

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please try to ask in the form of a question as it makes it easier to for others to directly address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Which SharePoint version are you using? May be you can monitor/check **SPLogs** while updating the content type.